# Is it OK for capacitor voltage rate for this circuit?

Tags: voltage-regulator, buck

[image]
I have a DC-DC buck converter circuit.

C5 capacitor in this circuit is 10uF with a voltage rating 10V(only available for me ).

is this circuit work as normal with 24V input??
or damaging c5(when input is present)?

[datasheet_LM2596](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lm2596.pdf)

Thanks.

Comment: The capacitor will explode. Is that OK?

Comment: Does this question even need to be asked?

Comment: "Is it okay to do what the capacitor vendor is telling me is NOT okay?"

Comment: @Transistor absence of C5 make any change?

Answer (score 4):

Of course not.

The answer must be longer for technical reasons, but there's really not much else to write.

Answer (score 3):

I'm assuming C5 is ceramic.  If so, it probably won't fail catastrophically, at least for a while...ceramic caps are fairly resilient to overvoltage.  However, 10uF would be a type 2 ceramic, and you'd be lucky to get even 1uf effective at 24V, since capacitance generally decreases with DC voltage (except for the first volt or so) and even within spec it will probably drop to 30% of its original value.

If it's not ceramic, then I'd worry more about early catastrophic failure.

But it's not a good idea either way.  If ceramic, you'd be better off with a higher voltage rating (in a bigger package) or a smaller capacitance in a similar package with a higher voltage rating.

Comment: The OP wrote that he used 10uF/10V....

Comment: I'm aware of that...I said it wouldn't fail *for a while* if ceramic.  It will probably fail eventually, but the main problem is it won't be near 10uF.  Other types of caps will fail more promptly (and often more spectacularly) when subjected to 150% overvoltage.

Comment: +1. A MLCC capacitor is unlikely to fail, but it will have **very** little capacitance with that much bias voltage.

Answer (score 0):

If capacitor is rated to 10V, you CANNOT use it at ANY higher voltage. Moreover, the good practice is to have na margin (minimum 15...20%), so you have to use capacitor rated to voltage one step over the voltage in your circuit. It means, that if you will have 24V on input, usage of 25V rated capacitor is bad choice too, the next step over will be 35V or 40V, so you need to use 10uF/35V or 10uF/40V.

Capacitor rated at 10V will probably explode in your circut (resulting in effect of absenve this capacitor), or will make short circuit on input.

Answer (score 0):

10µF 10V MLCC on 24V will not survive for long.

If you cannot get 10µF 50V ceramic capacitors, then use several 1µF 50V caps in parallel.

But honestly, I'm more worried about the 100µF 50V cap on the input, since that doesn't sound like a large enough value to have the required Ripple Current Rating and appropriate ESR to survive in this position. So make sure you check these specs.